# Cornelsen - Why pronounced with long "e"

Tags: pronunciation, person-names, vowel-length

I know the syllable structure is cor-nel-sen

So it should be pronounced with a short "e", isn't it?

Or maybe because it is a last name the rules don't apply here?

Comment: Pronounciation of personal names might follow their own rules.

Comment: Why would this syllable structure imply a short "e"?

Comment: Which "e" do you ask for? The first (in "nel") or the second (in "sen")?

Answer (score 6):

*Cornelsen* is a patronymic name as for example *Petersen* = *Peters Sohn* = son of Peter.

*Cornelsen* is derived from the first name *Cornelius,* which is of Latin origin and has similar accentuation of the *e.*

Comment: If you make an edit, please ping me - I would like to undo my downvote (due to clumsy mishandling of a mobile phone and noticing too late >.<)

Comment: It's worth mentioning however that not all [German words of Latin origin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_lateinischer_Lehn-_und_Fremdw%C3%B6rter_im_Deutschen) follow Latin word pronunciation rules such as stress position e.g, [Angina (La)](https://forvo.com/languages/la/) or [Agent(La)](https://forvo.com/languages/la/) vs. [Angina(Gr)](https://forvo.com/languages/de/) or [Agent(Gr)](https://forvo.com/languages/de/).